# What is the rule of taking a variable out of a sum?

Tags: analysis

I have the following function:

$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}*\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{P_i}{C_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{D_i}{Q_i}}  $$

I want to get $Q_i$ out of this function, but the solution has to remain the same. So I want a function of the form:

$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}*\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{P_i}{C_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n{D_i}} * 
 X$$

But what has to be in 'X' ? I tried several things, but I don't get the same solution.  What is the rule when you want to do this kind of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite straightforward to see that

$$X = \frac{\sum_i D_i}{\sum_i \frac{D_i}{Q_i}}$$

if the two expressions you provided are supposed to be equal, assuming that $\sum D_i \neq 0$ (you can do this by equating the two expressions and algebraically solve for $X$). But other than that I think is not possible to *factor out* $Q_i$ without $X$ depending on any of the $D_i$ or $P_i$ or $C_i$, since

$$\sum_i \frac{D_i}{Q_i} = \sum_i D_i \prod_{j\neq i} Q_j =(*).$$

You could write $(*) = \vec D \cdot \nabla_{Q_i} \left(\prod_j Q_j\right)$ and therefore $X = \frac{\vec D \cdot \vec 1}{\vec D \cdot \nabla_{Q_i} \left(\prod_j Q_j\right)}$ but I don't think that this helps much.

Comment: Thanks Flawr! I mistaken myself in the second function (see the edit of adding the $D_i$). What should be $X$ in this context?

Comment: Please don't change your question if it is already answered, instead ask a new one - I'm happy to answer!